# D3 cardinal line interpolation looks wrong

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying to give a polygon - drawn with d3 - smooth edges using the `d3.svg.line().interpolate()` option but I get strange looking results.

I receive the polygon data from the nokia HERE api as world coordinate data in the form `[lat1, long1, alt1, lat2, long2, alt2 ...]` So in the routingCallback  function - which is called when the response is in - I first refine it so it looks like this `[[lat1, long1], [lat2, long2] ...]`. In d3.svg.line() I then use this array of coordinates to calculate the pixel positions. Im using [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to draw the polygon on a map so I use the [map.latLngToLayerPoint()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-conversion-methods) function to do that. The actual drawing of the polygon happens in reset() which is called from the routingCallback immediately after the data is available and every time the map gets zoomed

```
var map = new L.Map("map", {"center": [52.515, 13.38], zoom: 12})
    .addLayer(new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/---account key---/120322/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'));

map.on("viewreset", reset);


var svg = d3.select(map.getPanes().overlayPane).append("svg"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("class", "leaflet-zoom-hide group-element"),

bounds = [[],[]],
polygon,
refinedData,

line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {                
        var location = L.latLng(d[0], d[1]),
            point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(location);
        return point.x; 
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        var location = L.latLng(d[0], d[1]),
            point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(location);
        return point.y;
    })
    .interpolate("cardinal"),

routingCallback = function(observedRouter, key, value) {
    if(value == "finished") {
        var rawData = observedRouter.calculateIsolineResponse.isolines[0].asArray(),
        refinedData = [];

        for(var i = 2; i < rawData.length; i += 3) {
            var lon = rawData[i-1],
                lat = rawData[i-2];

            refinedData.push([lat, lon]); 
        }

    if(polygon)
        polygon.remove();

    polygon = g
        .data([refinedData])
        .append("path")
            .style("stroke", "#000")
            .style("fill", "none")
            .attr("class", "isoline");             

        reset(); 
    }
    if(value == "failed") {   
        console.log(observedRouter.getErrorCause());
    }
};


getIsolineData = function(isoline) {

    return data;
};

function reset() {
    var xExtent = d3.extent(refinedData, function(d) {
        var location = L.latLng(d[0], d[1]);
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(location);
        return point.x;
    });

    var yExtent = d3.extent(refinedData, function(d) {
        var location = L.latLng(d[0], d[1]);
        var point = map.latLngToLayerPoint(location);
        return point.y;
    });

    bounds[0][0] = xExtent[0];
    bounds[0][1] = yExtent[0];
    bounds[1][0] = xExtent[1];
    bounds[1][1] = yExtent[1];

    var topLeft = bounds[0],
        bottomRight = bounds[1];

    svg .attr("width", bottomRight[0] - topLeft[0])
        .attr("height", bottomRight[1] - topLeft[1])
        .style("left", topLeft[0] + "px")
        .style("top", topLeft[1] + "px");

    g   .attr("transform", "translate(" + -topLeft[0] + "," + -topLeft[1] + ")");

    polygon.attr("d", line);
}
```

I expect this to produce smooth edges but instead I get a small loop at every corner. The red overlay is the same polygon without interpolation. There are only points at the corners. No points added inbetween.

[image: strange looking corners when using d3 cardinal interpolation. red overlay is the same polygon without interpolation]

Does it have something to do with the order of the points (clockwise/counter clockwise)? I tried to rearrange the points but nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: The order of the points shouldn't really matter in this case -- can you post a complete example please?

Comment: Are you trying to create the rounded corners by adding a point just before and after each corner?  In which case I think you're adding the before and after in incorrect order.  But more to the point, I don't think it's necessary -- the cardinal interpolation is intended to smooth out the corners with just the key points specified.  You can approximately control the radius of the corners by changing the [tension](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_tension) parameter on the line function.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I updated my post and added a more complete example.

Comment: @AmeliaBR I added a new Image of the polygon. The red overly shows what the polygon looks like without interpolation. There are only points at the corners without anything added inbetween

Comment: @Flavio Could you also please post a sample of your data so that we can reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can recreate the pattern you're getting is if I add every vertex to the path *twice*.  That wouldn't be noticeable with a linear interpolation, but causes the loops when the program tries to connect points smoothly.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/weuLs/

**Edit:**

Taking a closer look at your code, it looks like the problem is in your `calculateIsolineResponse` function; I don't see that name in the Leaflet API so I assume it's custom code.  You'll need to debug that to figure out why you're duplicating points.

If you can't change that code, the simple solution would be to run your points array through a filter which removes the duplicated points:

```
refinedData = refinedData.filter(function(d,i,a){
        return ( (!i) || (d[0] != a[i-1][0]) || (d[1] != a[i-1][1]) ); 
     });
```

That filter will return true if either it's the first point in the array, or if either the lat or lon value is different from the previous point.  Duplicated points will return false and be filtered out of the array.

Comment: Awesome, that was the exact problem! The calculateIsolineResponse is a property of the nokia HERE router which contains the response so I'm not able to modify that. But eliminating every second point after refining the data works. Thanks very much! The only question left is why the HERE api returns every point twice :) ?!